# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list when trying to remove an element with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, marc

I have a marc xml file with two records in a collection. I want to remove the 955 datafields from the file.

When I try and iterate through the list produced from `findall`, I get a `ValueError`, `list.remove(x): x not in list`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('toggle.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for a955 in root.findall('record/datafield[@tag="955"]'):
    root.remove(a955)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 6
      3 root = tree.getroot()
      5 for a955 in root.findall('record/datafield[@tag="955"]'):
----> 6     root.remove(a955)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Here is the xml I'm trying to modify (I've removed a few datafields for brevity):

```
<collection>
    <record>
        <leader>00859cam a2200277Ia 4500</leader>
        <controlfield tag="005">20170510144913.0</controlfield>
        <controlfield tag="008">880930s1983    enka          00010 eng d</controlfield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">ocm13279646 880930</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="9">0674-46060</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(StEdNL)1580610-nlsdb-Voyager</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2="0">
            <subfield code="a">Evans, Martin.</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="710" ind1="2" ind2="0">
            <subfield code="a">Health Education Council.</subfield>
            <subfield code="w">cn</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="710" ind1="2" ind2="0">
            <subfield code="a">Teachers' Advisory Council on Alcohol and Drug Education.</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="955" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">QP4.88.1745</subfield>
            <subfield code="b">QP4DOT88DOT</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="956" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">NLS</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
    <record>
        <leader>01030cas a2200349 i 4500</leader>
        <controlfield tag="005">20190312175642.0</controlfield>
        <controlfield tag="008">130830c20139999stkwr ne      0   a0eng d</controlfield>
        <datafield tag="015" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">GBB386135</subfield>
            <subfield code="2">bnb</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="022" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">2053-6496</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(Uk)016484976</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">2992934</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(StEdNL)5112576-nlsdb-Voyager</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="651" ind1=" " ind2="0">
            <subfield code="a">Troon (Scotland)</subfield>
            <subfield code="v">Newspapers.</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="651" ind1=" " ind2="0">
            <subfield code="a">South Ayrshire (Scotland)</subfield>
            <subfield code="v">Newspapers.</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="752" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">Scotland</subfield>
            <subfield code="b">Strathclyde</subfield>
            <subfield code="d">Troon.</subfield>
            <subfield code="2">blnpn</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="919" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">NBS</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="955" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="y">2020</subfield>
            <subfield code="b">V000258858</subfield>
        </datafield>
    </record>
</collection>
```

I was basing this on the example from the [`ElementTree docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file):

```
for country in root.findall('country'):
    # using root.findall() to avoid removal during traversal
    rank = int(country.find('rank').text)
    if rank > 50:
        root.remove(country)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something very basic incorrectly but I just can't work out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation:

> `remove(subelement)`
> Removes subelement from the element.

In that context a subelement is a *direct child* (sadly the ElementTree docs use very loose language so in other contexts subelement is used to qualify any element below the current one). `remove` is not going to iterate through the entire tree looking for the element you're asking it to remove.

The element you select is not a child of `root` (aka `collection`), it's a child of `record`. So you can't remove it via `root`, you need to get a handle on `record`.

Since as far as I know ElementPath is in pure python, you'd probably benefit from just implementing things longhand:

```py
for record in root.iter('record'):
    for c in reversed(record):
        if c.tag == 'datafield' and c.get('tag') == '955':
            record.remove(c)
```

You could also index and slice out the elements to remove but *that* seems a bit much.

Comment: Thanks, this works - why is reversed() necessary here?

Comment: We're removing elements of what is essentially a Python list. Python lists have no support for removal during iteration and are not *stable* under iteration, so let's say we're iterating `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, we're at "3" and we remove it, the list is now `[1, 2, 4, 5]`, the list and iterator don't sync their information so the next item we get is 5 rather than 4. By iterating from the end, we avoid this issue, from the end when we remove 3 the next item is 2 no matter what.

Comment: There are alternative solutions e.g. iterate on a copy (as long as you're removing by identity not index), collect all the elements we need to remove then doing a second pass to remove them (essentially what `findall` would do since it returns a list), moving the items we keep to an other list (then resetting), ....

Comment: great, that's much clearer now. I did noticed it worked without reversed() but I suspect that's just because I'm working with a very simple sample and no repeated fields. I'll keep it in for the full set.

Comment: Yes if the matches are sparse (which is the case here) and there are no consecutive matches then it's easy to miss the issue.